# How to disable automatic null checks for constructor parameters of a specific data class?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, validation, null

I have an endpoint in my Spring Boot app, e.g.

```
data class SomeRequest(
    @field:NotNull
    val someField: String?
)

@RestController
class SomeController {

    @PostMapping(value = ["/something"])
    fun something(@RequestBody @Valid someRequest: SomeRequest) {
        someRequest.someField!!
    }

}
```

And while I can be sure `someField` will never be `null`, I still need to add `!!` every time it is used.

Unfortunately, I cannot change the type of this field to `String` because then Kotlin will add an automatic null check to the constructor, causing deserialization to fail and preventing validations from being performed.

What I am looking for is a way to suppress addition of automatic null checks. Is there an annotation or something similar I could use on particular class / field? (wouldn't want to disable it globally)

```
data class SomeRequest(
    @field:NotNull
    @NoIntrinsicNullCheck
    val someField: String?
)
```

Comment: Do you mean during deserialization it is first set to null and then to the correct value? `lateinit` is exactly for such purposes.

Comment: remove `?` - `val someField: String`

Comment: @broot deserialization fails altogether because Kotlin throws `NullPointerException`. Also, "'lateinit' modifier is not allowed on primary constructor parameters".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Minimal working configuration

Maven:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

SpringBootApp:

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication
class SpringSandboxApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<SpringSandboxApplication>(*args)
}
```

And controller:

```kotlin
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import javax.validation.Valid
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull

data class NullRequest(
    @field:NotNull
    val someField: String
)

@RestController
class NullCheckController {

    @PostMapping(value = ["/something"])
    fun request(@RequestBody @Valid body: NullRequest): String {
        return body.someField
    }
}
```

I have no problem with data serialization:

```bash
usr@sars-cov-2 spring-sandbox % curl localhost:8080/something -X POST -d '{}' --header Content-Type:\ application/json   
{"timestamp":"2023-01-19T12:08:04.602+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","path":"/something"}%     

usr@sars-cov-2 spring-sandbox % curl localhost:8080/something -X POST -d '{"someField": "abc"}' --header Content-Type:\ application/json   
abc%
```

app logs:

> 2023-01-19 13:08:04.601  WARN 70989 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Instantiation of [simple type, class com.example.springsandbox.rest.NullRequest] value failed for JSON property someField due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter someField which is a non-nullable type; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.MissingKotlinParameterException: Instantiation of [simple type, class com.example.springsandbox.rest.NullRequest] value failed for JSON property someField due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter someField which is a non-nullable type at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: com.example.springsandbox.rest.NullRequest["someField"])]

### Handling nullability

According to your comment:

#### Intercepting the exception to map it into expected one

If you need to use the validation (and you expect a different exception), maybe it would be OK to just write a global exception handler that would intercept `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException` (that is thrown when the Spring cannot parse the request) to parse it and throw a custom exception (or `MethodArgumentNotValidException` to be consistent with the validation)? The logic would be pretty easy - if you detect such an exception just covert it. Such a handler would be trigger also if you would cause such an exception in your code.

#### Disabling the check globally

Just compile the code with -Xno-param-assertions. Then no checks would be present.

Is it bad running the app with checks disabled? Actually... This forces a proper integration between Java and Kotlin (to find the null-problems as soon as they are present) - because Kotlin code is safe, Java's not (so potential problem is that an integration with library or something could be broken).

#### Proguard

You can use tool like proguard that would remove those checks - globally, or basing on some annotation. Not sure how to configure it for Spring, and if it even possible.

#### Old, good Java

You still can write your models with old, plain Java :) With records, it's not so painful like it used to be.

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

public record NullRequest(
    @JsonProperty("someField") String someField,
    @JsonProperty("someFieldNullable") @Nullable String nullable
) {
}
```

What is quite surprising to me is that this guarantee the compile-time safety. Such a code would not compile:

```
    @PostMapping(value = ["/something"])
    fun request(@RequestBody @Valid body: NullRequest): String {
        body.someFieldNullable.get(0) // compile-error!
        return ""
    }

    // /Users/sars-cov-2/spring-sandbox/src/main/kotlin/com/example/springsandbox/rest/NullCheckController.kt:21:31
Kotlin: Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type String?
```

#### Backing fields

You still can add "backing fields" for your data class. Something like:

```
data class Data(private val _v: String?) {
    val v: String
        get() = _v!!
}
```

Comment: You are not getting the same results. Notice how the controller throws `HttpMessageNotReadableException`. Normally a validation failure results in `MethodArgumentNotValidException` instead.

Comment: (if you try the same request with `val someField: String?` the exception will be different)

Comment: Oh, now I get you. Added some possible solutions as an edit-part.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I actually went with just handling `HttpMessageNotReadableException` because disabling stuff globally sounds dangerous and records are a bit more annoying than data classes (;

Comment: It's a shame there is no way to disable these checks for a single class or even single constructor :(